# PHP that accepts file upload from a single HTTP POST

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm trying to figure out how to get a server to accept a file through HTTP post in one step - without going through all the trouble of creating an html form and clicking the submit button.

I know how to write a PHP/HTML package that accomplishes the following:

- user points their local browser to a URL with an upload form
- user selects a local file and clicks "upload" button on the form
- server accepts that file and places it in a specified place

I create an HTML file with a form that calls a php script when the submit button is clicked.

I'd like to change this to the following:

- From command line, user executes the following command:
        "curl -X POST @somefile http://myhost/getter.php"
- server (myhost) accepts that file and places it in a specified place

Said another way, I'd like to send the file directly to the php script without going through the form step.

Much thanks for any guidance.

Comment: This is easy enough to do. If you can make a form that posts to a script you can call that script directly with curl as well. Why do you think this would be any different?

Comment: I definitely agree that one should be able to call the script directly.  The devil is in the details...  :)  I haven't been able to get this to work because the $_FILE array isn't populated correctly when I call the script directly.

Comment: `$_FILES`* array. Apache should populate it for you. If not, maybe you're not using the right contenttype in cURL? It should be `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Sending the file as `curl --form file=@filename myhost/getter.php` seems to have worked.  The curl man page claims that using `--form` sends content type.  Once I do this, the `$_FILES` array is correctly populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html

4.3 File Upload POST

```
<form method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data' action="upload.cgi">
  <input type=file name=upload>
  <input type=submit name=press value="OK">
</form>
```

command line equivalent:

```
 curl --form upload=@localfilename --form press=OK [URL]
```

Comment: Very cool that curl has that option - thanks!  Ultimately, I'm going to have to accept data from a service instead of curl, so I'm going to need to solve this on the server side.

Comment: if your `$_FILE` array isn't populated, make sure you have `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in your form and high enough post_max_size / upload_max_filesize directives in php.ini (post_max_size >= 1.33 * upload_max_filesize)

Comment: The inclusion of the enctype seems to be the key here.  Thanks for the help.